# What does UDP mean to Fire and forget pattern technique?

Tags: design-patterns, tcp, udp, fire-and-forget

TCP/IP handles data transmission and always responds the HTTP's status.
If I apply Fire and forget pattern, does it use UDP?

Comment: This question makes no sense for me. TCP/IP has no such thing as a HTTP status - HTTP does. And HTTP can use TCP as the underlying transport layer (HTTP/1 and HTTP/2) but also UDP (HTTP/3).

Comment: I'm so sorry Steffen Ullrich for my typo.